# User Confirmation using a Userform Modeless and DoEvents

Tags: vba

Can this be done more efficiently?

The code does the following:

1. Do Stuff
2. Show UserForm and ask user to confirm the shown data is ok
3. User can manipulate and controll excel as usual
4. As soon as user clicks the "yes" button "do some other stuff" is called

**The Module**

```
Sub ControlDataUI()
Dim Ui As New UserForm1
Dim IsConfirmed As Boolean

Debug.Print "dostuff"

Application.ScreenUpdating=True
With Ui
    .Show (0)
    While Not .IsHiden
        DoEvents
    Wend
    If .IsCancelled Then Exit Sub
    IsConfirmed = .Confirmed
End With

Debug.Print "Do some more stuff!"

If IsConfirmed Then
    Debug.Print "SaveStuff"
End If

Debug.Print "I will die!!"
End Sub
```

**The UserForm**

```
Private Type TView
    IsCancelled As Boolean
    Confirmed As Boolean
    IsHiden As Boolean
End Type

Private this As TView
Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
    IsCancelled = this.IsCancelled
End Property
Public Property Get Confirmed() As Boolean
    Confirmed = this.Confirmed
End Property
Public Property Get IsHiden() As Boolean
    IsHiden = this.IsHiden
End Property

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Debug.Print "YES!!!!"
this.Confirmed = True
this.IsHiden = True
Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Debug.Print "NO?!?!"
this.Confirmed = False
this.IsHiden = True
Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
this.IsCancelled = True
Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
Debug.Print "Murder! I was killed!"
End Sub
```

So the idea was in the right direction but the while loop had to contain a `DoEvents` in order to process the events comming from the user.

Summary:

**1. Modeless Userform**

**2. While loop with `DoEvents` until user confirmes**

This allows for the user controll of the sheet and a confirmation at any time. The code will run after the user confirms the data is ok.

Answer (score 4):

Yup, it's wrong<sup>1</sup> :)

Forms (and literally everything in Windows) *already* run their own message loop: whenever you feel the need to wrap a form with a no-op "wait until user does something" `DoEvents` loop, you are essentially forcing your form into a procedural dialog paradigm, keeping the VBA runtime much, *much* more busy than it needs to be.

Embrace the objects!

The idiomatic way to handle this in VBA is to adopt an event-driven paradigm: instead of wait-looping for a state change and essentially "poll" your form periodically until its `.IsHiden` (typo?) state changes, have a *presenter* class that's responsible for dealing with the state of the form, by responding to its *events*.

```
Dim Ui As New UserForm1
```

Instead of a local (auto-instantiated?) object variable, make that a `WithEvents` variable at module level (that's why you need a class: only class modules can have `WithEvents` variables).

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents UI As UserForm1

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set UI = New UserForm1
End Sub
```

Now this class can handle any of the `UI` events - whether they're inherited from the `UserForm` base class, or custom-defined on the `UserForm1` default interface, like this:

```
Public Event ByeBye()

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Debug.Print "YES!!!!"
    this.Confirmed = True
    this.IsHiden = True
    Me.Hide
    RaiseEvent ByeBye
End Sub
```

Note the indentation is made more consistent (and arguably better, IMO) by adding an indent level for all members.

Doing this allows the presenter class (the one that declares a `WithEvents` instance of the form) to handle this `ByeBye` event:

```
Private Sub UI_ByeBye()
    'form is no longer displayed
End Sub
```

Note that this is an entirely different paradigm: you can't `do stuff` in the same procedure that's responsible for showing the form anymore - it *forces* you to separate the responsibilies!

---

<sup>1</sup> Only because the form isn't modal though: a modal form suspends execution, which makes the explicit loop useless; the form's state can be read on the statement that immediately follows the call to `.Show`, since that next instruction will only run after the form is dismissed. That isn't the case for a non-modal form, so instead of loop-waiting, we need to embrace the asynchronous nature of the non-modal messenging, with events.

Comment: Not that it's particularly relevant to your review, but what do you mean by the line "whether they're inherited from the UserForm base class, or custom-defined on the UserForm1 default interface"? I was under the impression that the `UserForm1` class defines an interface which _extends_ the base UserForm class' interface (by inheriting methods and events like `show` etc. and defining new ones). But what's 'default' got to do with anything, we're not referring to the pre declared instance of `UserForm1` right? Sorry, I'm not hugely familiar with these concepts since they can't be copied in VBA

Comment: @Greedo the "default interface" of a class is the interface presented by an object declared `As [ClassName]` - in other words `As UserForm1` includes the members of `UserForm` inherited from the base class, *and* the members of `UserForm1` defined in `UserForm1`, but not the members of `IDialogView` defined in some hypothetical `IDialogView` class that `UserForm1` would be implementing with `Implements IDialogView`.

Comment: @TinMan that sample code involves a *modal* form though. Non-modal forms demand a different paradigm, an event-driven approach. I don't recall writing about non-modal forms, since I don't use them much. But yeah, I'm definitely open for debate - who's the author? ;-)